# Get the number of r length permutations/combinations from n non distinct elements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm currently working on a website, which will animate all the possible, combinations, permutations of distinct or non distinct objects (depending on input).
[Example of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDhU8.png)

In the above example there are 10 elements, and I want to get all the 2 element permutations, but there are only 2 unique type of elements.So the number of permutations in this case is:4 ([red,red],[orange,orange],[red,orange],[orange,red]).
And the number of combinations is:3 ([red,red],[orange,orange],[red,orange])

I acctualy managed the programming part of the problem, and it works perfectly for any input, but i used "Heap's algorithm",

- *it generates each unique(!) permutation from the previous one,(for combinations I create an array of length n, which contains n-r zeros
  and r ones, and I use Heap's algorithm to get the permutations of
  this array of zeros and ones,and the indexes of ones tell me which
  elements i need to choose from the initial set of elements to get the
  next combination,if the objects aren't distinct i remeber each unique combination and i use a while loop that keeps using heap's algorithm on the array of zeros and ones until it finds the next unique combination(it actually works even for 15 elements) )*

So I don’t actualy know the number of permutations or combinations until I get to the end of the animation. I have to calculate the actual number of permutations/combinations seperatly, but I can't figure out an equation if the elements aren't distinct.

Is there a way around this problem?

Comment: The best general approach I know is via “generating functions.” If there are $m_i$ elements of type $i,$ for $i=1,\dots,k,$ the number of combinations of size $n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product: $$\left(1+x+\cdot+x^{m_1}\right)\cdots\left(1+x+\cdots x^{m_k}\right)$$ The permutation count is $n!$ times the coefficient if $x^n$ of the product: $$\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=0}^{m_i}\frac{x^j}{j!} $$ Combinations are much easier than permutations.

Comment: When $k=2,$ for example, the formula in the first case is the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$\frac{(1-x^{m_1+1})(1-x^{m_2+1})}{(1-x)^2}$$ is $$\binom{n+1}{1}-\binom{n-m_1}{1}-\binom{n-m_2}{1}+\binom{n-1-(m_1+m_2)}{1}.$$ When $n\leq \min(m_1,m_2)$ this is just $n+1.$ When $m_1<n<m_2$ this is $m_1+1.$ If $\max(m_1,m_2)\leq n\leq m_1+m_2,$ this is $m_1+m_2-(n+1).$ Permutations, are more complicated. Specifically: $$\sum_{\substack{0\leq i\leq m_1\\0\leq j\leq m_2\\i+j=n}} \binom n{i}$$

Comment: When $n\leq \min(m_1,m_2)$ this is $2^n.$ When $m_1<n<m_2$ there isn’t a closed formula for $$\sum_{i=0}^{m_1}\binom{n}i$$ When $m_1\leq m_2\leq n\leq m_1+m_2,$ you get $$\sum_{j=n-m_1}^{m_2}\binom{n}{j}$$

Comment: In your case, when $m_1=4,m_2=6,$ and $p_n$ is the number of permutations of $n$ objects, you get: $$(p_n)=(1,2,4,8,16,31,57,98,154,210,210).$$

Comment: Edit to earlier comment. When $\max(m_1,m_2)\leq n\leq m_1+m_2,$ the combinations are $m_1+m_2+1-n.$

Comment: In general, for $k>2,$ the formula gets even messier. If $$S_{n}=\{(i_1,\dots,i_k)\mid 0\leq i_j\leq m_j\text{ and }\sum_j i_j=n,$$ then the number of combinations is just $|S_n|,$ which can be computed with an inclusion-exclusion formula which might have up to $2^k$ terms, but the permutations are $$\sum_{(i_j)_{j=1}^k\in S_n}\binom{n}{i_1,\dots,i_k},$$ the sum of multinominals. You get the formula $k^n$ when $n\leq \min_j(m_j),$ but for other $n$ it is a lot more complicated.